# Views Render Link Field

Tags: views, theming

I am trying to render some fields of a view...

this code works nearly perfect:

```
$view = views_get_view('<name>');
$view->execute('<name 2>');
$view->render_field('title', 0); //works!
$view->render_field('view_node', 0); //does not work, should be a link
```

"view_node" should be handled by "views_handler_field_node_link" but does not output anything...

Can anybody help??

Thanks in Ahead!